CORS error occurring when using Flask-cors library and/or flask decorators on routes
I have built an endpoint using Flask with Python.
The client is running on localhost:4200 the API is running on localhost:5000 simultaneously.
According to what I have found. There is no issue with how I have everything ordered, and the cors-flask library should be doing it's job. That is according to this forum post Flask-CORS Error
You will see that I have set up CORS(app), as specified by the Flask CORS documentation, in my app.py file below.
from flask import Flask
from api.utils.db import DB
from api.route.home import base
from api.route.analytics import analytics
from flask_cors import CORS

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}},  origins="*", methods=['GET', 'POST'], allow_headers=['Content-Type'])

    base.register_blueprint(analytics)    
    app.register_blueprint(base)

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=5000, type=int, help='port to listen on')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    port = args.port
    
    db = DB()

    try:
        db.check_connection()
        app = create_app()
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
    except Exception as e:
        print (f"{e}")

After that did not work, I tried adding a simple decorator @cross-origins to the base route of the analytics endpoints, specified by a potential solution found in How to enable CORS in flask
I also attempted to use the after_request decorator, which is supposed to modify the headers before the response completes. This also failed.
The ClinicAnalytics below refers to a mapped SQLAlchemy Model, no external API calls are happening.
analytics.py
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, Response
from sqlalchemy import select
from api.model import ClinicAnalytics, engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from api.service.analytics_service import AnalyticsService
from flask_cors import cross_origin

analytics = Blueprint("analytics", __name__,  url_prefix='/analytics')
analytics_service = AnalyticsService()

@analytics.route("/", methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin(origins="*")
def analytics_home():
    with Session(engine) as session: 
        rows = session.query(ClinicAnalytics).all()

        return analytics_service.rows_to_object(rows)
        

@analytics.route("/clinic")
def analytics_clinic():
    pass

@analytics.after_request
def fix_headers(response: Response):
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Content-Type, X-Requested-With"

    return response

The API is currently open, and I am requiring no Authorization headers at this time.
I have tried multiple different content-types, and origins, no combination works.
To summarize everything:

Is there a different order I need place the CORS class in the app.py file?
If the order of that class is okay, then do I need to remove anything?
If I do not need to remove anything is this because I am using two localhost endpoints?

